# Using String.endswith() method on Java

Tags: java

I have an array I want to check the the last digits if it is in the array.

Example:

```
String[] types = {".png",".jpg",".gif"}

String image = "beauty.jpg";
// Note that this is wrong. The parameter required is a string not an array.
Boolean true = image.endswith(types);
```

Please note:
I know I can check each individual item using a for loop.

I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this. Reason being is that image string is already on a loop on a constant change.

Comment: Are you really attempting to name a boolean "true"?  Or is that for some demonstration purposes?

Comment: @GearsdfGearsdfas true is a reserved keyword by Java. And it's just not a very good variable name anyway- not very descriptive.

Comment: oh LOL i wasn't thinking of using true it just happened. @DavidB

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Arrays.asList(types).contains(image.substring(image.lastIndexOf('.') + 1))
```

Comment: Even simpler than mine. :) Does asList actually convert the array to a list every time?

Answer (score 5):

You can substring the last 4 characters:

`String ext = image.substring(image.length - 4, image.length);`

and then use a `HashMap` or some other search implementation to see if it is in your list of approved file extensions.

`if(fileExtensionMap.containsKey(ext)) {`

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays.asList to convert to a List. Then you can check for membership.

```
String[] types = {".png",".jpg",".gif"};
String image = "beauty.jpg";
if (image.contains(".")) 
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(types).contains(
        image.substring(image.lastIndexOf('.'), image.length())));
```